# Compute almost sure limit of martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Let $Y$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $\dots$, be nonnegative i.i.d random variables with mean $1$. Let 
>   $$X_n = \prod_{1\le m \le n}Y_m$$
>   If $P(Y = 1) < 1$, prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n = 0$ almost surely.

I feel like this question has something to do with the idea that $(X_n)$ is a martingale (which I can prove easily) but I am not sure if I am overthinking it or not. I was trying to use Doob's upcrossing inequalities in a clever way but there might be an easier approach to the problem.

Comment: If $Y_m = 1$ then the limit is $1$

Comment: take logarithm at both sides then apply the strong law of large number. Use Jensen's inequality to see $E\log Y_1<0$ unless $Y_1$ is constant

Comment: Sorry I missed the assumption that Y is *not* almost surely 1. That is, P(Y = 1) < 1.

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle I'm not sure how that solves the problem. First of all I only get that E[log X_n] > 0 for all n using that approach. Second, we don't know for sure that log(Y_n) is in L1...

Comment: @Bob I've made an answer

Comment: 1 Bob, what is Y? 2 @Ilya is $Y_m = 1$ ?

Comment: @BCLC I made that comment before the edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\dfrac{\log X_n}{n} = \dfrac{\sum_{m \le n} \log Y_m}{n} \to E\log Y_1$ almost surely by the strong law of large number.

And by Jensen's inequality, $E\log Y_1 \leq \log EY_1 =0$ since $EY_1 = 1$.

Since $P(Y = 1) < 1$, $E\log Y_1 < \log EY_1 =0$.

So we get that $\dfrac{\log X_n}{n}$ converges to a strictly negative number almost surely, thus $\log X_n \to -\infty$, i.e. $X_n \to 0$

Comment: @BCLC An independent copy of $Y_1$

Comment: You mean Y is also nonnegative iid with mean 1? Actually what does $P(Y=1) < 1$ have to do with anything? I think you mean 'since $E(Y_1) = 1$' ?

Comment: @BCLC $P(Y=1) < 1$ excludes the case where $Y$ is a constant almost surely, so Jensen's inequality is strict

Comment: Wait how do you know $P(Y_1 = 1) < 1$ from $P(Y = 1) <1$ ?

Comment: Wait $Y=Y_m$ ? As in all the RVs have probability of equalling their mean less than 1?

Comment: @BCLC $Y$ and all the $Y_m$'s are i.i.d. i.e. independent and identically distributed

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle How can you show that $E | \log Y_m | < \infty$?

Comment: @cdamle Reverse Jensen's? $E|\log Y_m| \le |E[\log Y_m]|$