# Martingales: Expectation of almost-sure limit

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation, martingales

Let $X_n, n\geq 0$ be a martingale. We know that $E[X_n]=E[X_m]$ for all $m, n \geq 0$. Moreover suppose that $X_n \rightarrow X$ P-a.s.

What do we know about $E[X]$? Is it clear that $E[X]=E[X_0]$?

What if $X_n$ is a submartingale? Is it clear that $E[X] \geq E[X_0]$? And the analogous result for a supermartingale?

What if the convergence is not P-a.s. but in $L^p$ for some $p \geq 1$?

Answer (score 3):

$X := \lim X_n$ right?

Well we want to know if $E[\lim X_n] = \lim E[X_n] (= \lim E[X_0] = E[X_0])$.

Depending on the $X_n$, we may or may not have $E[\lim X_n] = \lim E[X_n]$.

We could use Fatou's Lemmas to say that

$$E[\liminf X_n] \le \liminf E[X_n] \le \limsup E[X_n] \le E[\limsup X_n] \to E[\lim X_n] = \lim E[X_n]$$

but we need the $X_n$'s to satisfy the assumptions of Fatou's Lemmas

---

For a super/sub mart, we have:

$$E[X] := E[\lim X_n] \stackrel{if}{=} \lim E[X_n] \le / \ge \lim E[X_0] = E[X_0]$$

Comment: So do I get this right that the (sub/super)-martingale must be non-negative such that Fatou's Lemma can be applied and then the above holds?

Comment: @user136457 check assumptions of fatou's lemma :P

Comment: Thanks, I got confused a lot of things in my last comment. So I know now that Fatou's Lemma can help us, but only for supermartingales, to relate $E[X]$ and $E[X_0]$. 

Can you state some more conditions such that I could swap the lim and the expectation?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the product-martingale 
$$X_n = \prod_{1\le m \le n}Y_m$$
with $Y$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $\dots$, be non-negative, non-degenerate i.i.d random variables with mean $1$. Then you can prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n = 0$ almost surely (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067486/compute-almost-sure-limit-of-martingale)). But, obviously $$E[X_n]=E\left[\prod_{1\le m \le n}Y_m\right]=\prod_{1\le m \le n}E[Y_m]=1$$ by the independence of $Y_i$, for any $n\in \mathbb N$, so that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}E[X_n]=1=E[X_1]\neq0=E[X]$$ 
Trivially $X_n$ is a submartingale (and a supermartingale), so that $E[X]=0\not\ge 1=E[X_1]$ even for submartingales. Now, if $$X_n\overset{\mathcal L^p}\longrightarrow X$$ (which is the case for example if the Martingale convergence theorem applies) then you know that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}E[|X_n|^r]=E[|X|^r]$$ for all $1\le r\le p$ (this is a direction implication of $\mathcal L^p$ convergence, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean)).

Comment: I am really a beginner, so I am not sure about this. But isn't $X_n$ non-negative, hence we can apply Fatou which would yield the result using the above answer?

Comment: I am a beginner too, so maybe I am wrong too. Yes, you can apply Fatou's Lemma on the $X_n$'s, but which result exactly do you mean? There are several results.

Comment: @user136457 Perhaps fatou's lemmas don't apply?